# cordova - Error: Failed to fetch platform android

Tags: android, cordova, project, hybrid-mobile-app

I installed cordova and create a new project.

But when I use this command to add android platform:

> cordova platform add android

this error appears:

```
Error: Failed to fetch platform android 
Probably this is either a connection problem, or platform spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and platform name/version/URL.
Error: version not found: cordova-android@5.1.0
```

This is how I created the new project:

> cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld

And this is my SDK Manager:

[image: SDK Manager]

But I can add ios platform (But I work on Windows)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I had the same problem with the android@5.1.1 version. I solved this issue, checking what version of android is provided by cordova. You can check it in C:/Users/%USER%/.cordova/lib/npm-cache/cordova-android

Then, you install the android platform version provided. For me it was @5.1.0 which was in my cordova-android folder. So I used the cmd line following:

cordova platform add android@5.1.0 which should be a differnet version for you.

Kind regards !

Comment: Hi my  C:/Users/%USER%/.cordova/lib/ folder is empty. what has went wrong

Comment: What's that same path on macOS?

Answer (score 24):

Had the same issue after using nvm to switch node version. 
Just removing android platform and reinstalling it works for me:

```
cordova platform rm android && cordova platform add android
```

Comment: I'm guessing there is some caching somewhere with regards to the platform because the `android` platform wasn't in my config.xml but removing the platform and re-adding it fixed the problem. Interesting.

Answer (score 8):

you can check the android version provided by cordova by typing `cordova platform ls` inside projectname/cordova folder. I refered from below url https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/.
(For me .cordova/lib folder was empty).

Then add that platform from inside project's cordova folder by executing `cordova platform add android@5.1.1` (in my case, solved the issue).

Answer (score 5):

In my case after so many attempts, I solved the issue by running this command:

```
sudo npm install npm@4.6.1 -g
```

Then I was able to add platform and build my project.

Answer (score 4):

There seems to be an error with android@6.2.x and later. I had the same issue and using the below step was able to build my apk.

Do the following:

```
cordova platform remove android
```

Then add 6.1.2 specifically

```
cordova platform add android@6.1.2
```

Also found the following as an temporary workaround

```
cordova platform add android --nofetch
```

Answer (score 3):

Add `C:\Windows\System32` at the end of your `path` in environment variables if not exist before.
Then close cmd and open it again and run:

> cordova platfom add android

Comment: Could you explain why this is required?

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem today, none of the answers mentioned above works for me.
It turns out to be a permission problem, just simply add a `sudo` ahead.

```bash
sudo cordova platform add android
```

I am using Mac OS by the way

Comment: use `sudo cordova platform add android`

Comment: i think wipe data and cold boot after add/rm platform above as normal user should work.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue the way I fixed it was I did the following.

1. run the command `ionic platform add android` This should fail and give the error your getting.
2. It should have added a dependency to app.module.js. Now in here find "cordova-android" check it version at the time of this comment my version was 7.1.4.
3. Open android studio and go to to project setting and make sure u have the download the same version SDK. For me this was 7.1 Nugget.
4. create a new emulator with the same version and keep the emulator running.
5. Go back too your IDE close it and restart the IDE.
6. Run this command `cordova platform rm android && cordova platform add android`
7. DONE! Doing this fixed my issue.

The reason I found it was not fetching was because cordova was looking for Andriod SDK matching the version 7.1.4 but was not able to find it at the preset location normal "andriod/Sdk".

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, however, the issue was a missing peer dependency on `acorn`.

Adding `acorn` to the `devDependencies` section of my `package.json` did the trick.

So my suggestion is to look for missing peer dependencies and add them to the `devDependencies` section of your `package.json`.

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to remove the android platform from my project directory using this command: `cordova platform rm android`, it failed.But I managed to do it using the following steps:

1. I deleted `cordova-android` folder manually from `node_modules`.
2. Removed `cordova-android` dependency from `package.json`.
3. Executed this command from terminal : `cordova platform add android --nofetch`.

After these the Platform was added successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Did you copy or clone your project from somewhere else? Normally these errors have to do with incompatibilities between your cordova version and your platform configuration files.

update your cordova to the latest version

```
npm -g update cordova
```

Then remove and add the platform again

```
cordova platform rm android && cordova platform add android
```

Answer (score 0):

it just because cannot dowload cordova-android package.Just do it like this,it is done:
cnpm install cordova-android@^7.1.4 --save

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue and fixed it by performing following steps.

1. Add `C:\Windows\System32` in envrionment variable paths
2. Ensure `jdk/bin` path is setup under `JAVA_HOME` and path
3. Ensure SDK path is setup under `ANDROID_HOME` and path

Answer (score 0):

In my case(MacOS),

1. Run the command `cordova platform rm android`
2. Check package.json successfully deleted cordova-android.
3. Run the command `sudo cordova platform add android`
4. It worked.:)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue. Even new app created with `cordova create` had same issue.

What solved it for me was running

```
npm cache clean --force
```

And then reinstall dependencies

```
cordova platform add android
```

Answer (score 0):

My experience when running the below command in vs code was purely a permissions issue:

```
cordova platform add android
```

closing vs code and opening again running as admin did the trick on my windows machine

Answer (score 0):

If you have a space character after the platform name, it will cause this problem.
Just remove it.