# Cordova Error: Failed to fetch platform android

Tags: android, cordova, certificate, self, signed

I run the commond

```
>cordova platform add android
```

There has been such a mistake following

> Error: Failed to fetch platform android
>   Probably this is either a connection problem, or platform spec is incorrect.
>   Check your connection and platform name/version/URL.
>   Error: self signed certificate

But I run

```
>npm i cordova-android
```

It is normal operation.

I want to know who can help me.

Comment: you using mac or windows

Comment: @TonyYan I guess the key here is the "Error: self signed certificate" message in error trace. Are you using any self signed cerfiticates? Could you try adding this - '<preference name="debuggable" value="true"/>' in config.xml and build again?

Answer (score 0):

Solved this issue, checking what version of android is provided by cordova. You can check it in C:/Users/%USER%/.cordova/lib/npm-cache/cordova-android

Then, you install the android platform version provided. For me it was @5.1.0 which was in my cordova-android folder. So I used the cmd line following:

cordova platform add android@5.1.0 which should be a differnet version for you.

Comment: i‘m ~/.cordova/lib/ directory is empty

Comment: I think the main cause of the error is Error: self signed certificate
But I do not know the key to this problem lies.

Comment: @Younas i am afraid that this suggestion resolves the issue. I could see the response in the following link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35451207/cordova-error-failed-to-fetch-platform-android. But there the problem trace is different

Comment: @TonyYan Try out the suggestion i commented and keep us posted

Comment: I added in the configuration file in the command window ’<preference name="debuggable" value="true"/>‘ but still no change.

My profile is npm use a proxy, but I can run npm install command is normal.

Comment: @TonyYan Are you using any self signed certificates?