# Error: Failed to fetch platform android

Tags: android, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app, hybrid

I'm new to hybrid/cordova app. Whenever I'm running **cordova platform add android --save** I'm getting the following error.

*Error: Failed to fetch platform android

Probably this is either a connection problem, or platform spec is incorrect.

Check your connection and platform name/version/URL.

Error: Cannot find module 'fs-vacuum'*

I'm using windows 8.1 and I have set all environment variables as per cordova document.

For me .cordova/lib folder is empty. And I can't find cordova folder inside my projectname. cordova platform add android@5.1.1 is also not solved my issue.

c:\user\siva> cordova platform ls

Installed platforms:

Available platforms:
amazon-fireos ~3.6.3 (deprecated)
android ~5.1.1
blackberry10 ~3.8.0
browser ~4.1.0
firefoxos ~3.6.3
webos ~3.7.0
windows ~4.3.1
wp8 ~3.8.2 (deprecated)

Please help me.

Comment: this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35451207/cordova-error-failed-to-fetch-platform-android?rq=1