# Adding Cordova Platforms

Tags: javascript, java, android, apache, cordova

[image]
Hey, Guys! I recently started to work with Cordova and when I run the `Cordova platform add android` i get the following error. I have successfully placed the environment variables for Java and for the Android SDK as well. But the npm modules does not exist in C:/Windows/System32/npm as shown in the error, It is in the Users/My username/AppData/Roaming/npm folder. Some guidance would be appreciated.

I followed the following scripts which are shown in the official Cordova documentation to create a new project.

```
Cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
cd hello
Cordova platform add android -> where I'm stuck at
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly Check the Android Version Provided by Cordova and verify with your current Android version installed on your system , if there a mismatch :
1) Update Android Version From Android Studio SDK Manager
2) Update Cordova Platform - Refer: Cordova Documentation

External Source 
[cordova - Error: Failed to fetch platform android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35451207/cordova-error-failed-to-fetch-platform-android)

Comment: Could you please verify me as shown above, Is it indicating that I dont have any platforms installed currently as Installed platforms indicates empty ?

Comment: Do u have android Studio Installed on your System ?

Comment: Yes I do And the SDK does match as well

Comment: Once take reference from https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/platform_plugin_versioning_ref/ hope this help !

Comment: Check whether u have proper connectivity & installed node correctly or not

Comment: @Madpop Yes I have and thats not the problem it seems

Comment: Did u installed android images and sdk tools

Comment: @Madpop Yeah i did

Answer (score 0):

I figured out halfway what the the problem was. There was a file named 'npm' in my C:/Windows/System32 directory wich was of 0kb size, and once i deleted it, the error vanished. But not all the way though. I was able to install the browser platform but not the android platform via `cordova platform add android` or even specifying what the matching cordova-andriod pluggin to be with `cordova platform add andriod@version`.
 Only through the `cordova platform add https://github.com/apache/cordova-android.git` script I could install the andriod platform and once it was done other steps worked fine, and the project ran through the Android AVD. Any idea why the normal command to add the android platform didnt work, Just want to know but if it happens again i think Im gonna have to run the get from git command again. Thanks

[image]
[image]