# An error occurred while running ionic cordova build android --prod --release

Tags: java, android, ionic-framework, gradle, sdk

I'm new to the ionic framework. I've already set the path of gradle and java on the Environmental variables on Windows 7. Kindly check the errors on the image below. Hope anyone can help me. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Try posting your code into the question, instead of as a linked image - it's much easier to help if it's easy to read

Comment: Thanks for the head up mob. I'll do it in my incoming concern. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use **ionic cordova platform add android** first and then your command.

Comment: First of all, Thank you for your feedback. But it says that Cordova:Error: Failed to fetch platform cordova-android@^6.4.0 Probably this is either a connection problem, or platform spec is incorrect. Error:cmd: Command failed with exit code ENOENT

Answer (score 0):

> CordovaError: No Platform Added

The error clearly states that no platform is added, Please use the below command to add respective platforms

```
cordova platform add android/ios
```

Once the platform is successfully added then build .apk or .ipr file

```
 cordova build android/ios
```

Comment: First of all, Thank you for your feedback. But it says that Cordova:Error: Failed to fetch platform cordova-android@^6.4.0 Probably this is either a connection problem, or platform spec is incorrect. Error:cmd: Command failed with exit code ENOENT

Comment: I think this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35451207/cordova-error-failed-to-fetch-platform-android) can help you further